# fsockopen is returning null for paypal callback

Tags: php, iis, paypal-ipn

There are a lot of questions in stackoverflow similar to this topic and I have tried everyone of them, but to no avail. It might be my server configuration or something, so posting if anyone has any clue.

This is my code:-

```
$this->gateway['submit_url'] = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$this->gateway['callback_url'] = 'ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com:443';

//headers
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host www.ipnpb.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($req)."\r\n\r\n";

$fp= fsockopen($this->gateway['callback_url'], 443, $error_no, $error_msg, 60);
```

$req is defined above somewhere in the code.

Here fp returns null. My OpenSSL version is: OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014

I have windows IIS server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try removing port number `:443` from `$this->gateway['callback_url']` ?

`$this->gateway['callback_url'] = 'ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com';`

Port `443` is already passed in `fsockopen` function call.

`$fp= fsockopen($this->gateway['callback_url'], 443, $error_no, $error_msg, 60);`

**Edit**: ( Editing answer as new lines are now allowed in comments )

Is there anything else around this part of this code?

- there is missing semicolon (;) at the end of second line
- there is no $req defined.

Same code wrapped in a class with 3 changes suggested above is working for me.
( returns a resource of type stream )

```
<?php
class abc {
    public $gateway;

    public function __construct() {
        $req = 'ABCD';

        $this->gateway['submit_url'] = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        $this->gateway['callback_url'] = 'ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com';
        //headers
        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host www.ipnpb.paypal.com\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($req)."\r\n\r\n";

        $fp= fsockopen($this->gateway['callback_url'], 443, $error_no, $error_msg, 60);

        var_dump($fp);

    }
}
$a = new abc();
```

Comment: Please check new edits. [Removed earlier comment as it was difficult to format]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer and the effort in going through my code. I must have missed the semicolon while writing here. It is present in the actual code. And $req is defined above somewhere in the code,  if you believe it might cause the error then I will check it and get back.

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Comment: Nope. I think the code shown above is correct then. Might be some other issue. Do you have any hints on the approach to debugging this problem?

Comment: Can you try running the code I shared on your machine to check if this works ? If it works then try substituting your `$req`.

Comment: your code is fine.  just need to add colon in front of Host like 'Host:' for validity.